# Is there a way to set initially the row height for resizable rows?

Tags: javascript, jquery, tabulator

When using `textarea` fields in a row, the row can become very tall in `height`. Is there a way to initially set a `max-height` of cell/rows and just make them bigger when necessary?

Comment: Please provide a small working example to reproduce the issue. Paste your html, javascript and all related code to help others understand the problem.

Comment: solved it, after loading the tabulator: 

$('.tabulator-cell').css('height','24px');

Answer (score 0):

To extend on your initial answer, that wont work for all rows if you have the virtual DOM enabled.

It is extremely bad practice to try and manipulate elements inside the table as they could be replaced at any time, tabulator only renders the visible rows, others are created and destroyed as the table is scrolled so trying to apply heights like that will not work reliably in most cases.

In your case I would suggest setting it in CSS after you have imported the `tabulator.css` file:

```css
.tabulator .tabulator-row tabulator-cell{
    height:24px
}
```